# How can I get rid of emulated External SD storage, to allow using a real SD?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, external-sd, internal-sd

I have a Visual Land Prestige Elite 10Q tablet (KitKat 4.4.2, rooted with KingRoot), and have discovered that even after rooting and using a utility to "fix" the SD to be writable from KitKat, I can't move applications to the SD using X-Plore or App2SD, though I can now write files and create folders there.

Based on the error messages I've received from App2SD, this appears to be due to the manufacturer of my tablet having created an emulated external SD using dynamically allocated space in the internal storage (16 GB, so I'm not short on storage yet, at least).  I believe that if I can get rid of this internal_sd storage, move its contents to external_sd, and change the appropriate OS settings so it looks for external_sd, I'll be able to move/install apps to SD.

There don't seem to be any specific ROMs for this device, so flashing to Lollipop or Marshmallow is risky -- I'd prefer to get KitKat to behave, if possible, though I'll consider forcing an upgrade if I must.  I also don't have dozens of hours to spend fooling with this thing.

So, the real question: how can I convince the device to ignore or delete the internal_sd and use external_sd instead?

Update: I've installed a root terminal app, and appear to have access (as `su`) to the root file system, but I don't find `/system/etc/vold.fstab`.

Comment: Good question. I also would like to know if this is operationally viable. Hopefully some of SE's Gurus will have an answer for you (and me). The correct location would be /system/etc/vold.fstab

Comment: I'm not finding `/system/etc/vold.fstab` on my system.  I've read that Android changed how they control mounting storage between 4.3 and 4.4, eliminating or reducing dependence on this file.  Now I guess I'll have to look up what they changed to.

Comment: Thats the location on my LG 4.4.2 Use total commander (or something like) and search your system

Comment: I just searched with X-Plore's search and found no entry anywhere for `vold.fstab`.  In searching for `vold.*`I found a `vold` folder, and two files named `vold` with no extension; one of those was empty, the other 98 kB and appeared to contain non-ASCII data.  Searching for `*.fstab* came up blank.

Comment: If you open the 98kB file with a text editor, there should be a license/disclaimer from Linux. At the end, there should be a reference to a location on your device. If thats not what you see, then the manufacturer has deviated from the "norm".

Comment: That 98kB file is `/bin/vold` -- but as far as I can tell with a text editor, it doesn't have either a Linux license statement, a disclaimer, or a path to the actual `fstab` equivalent at the end.  It does seem to have a lot of embedded clear text, some of it file paths/names, but it seems to mostly consist of output messages for some program (likely itself).